# Excluding folders in bash loop

Tags: git, bash, github, git-bash

I'm trying to write a script to separate a GitHub repo with many projects all into separate repos while retaining their git history. I know how to do all of it by hand, but wanted to save time by writing a script to do it for me.

Here's what I have so far

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO_DIR="C:/Users/Jerred/GitKraken/harding-computer-science/"

cd "$REPO_DIR"

for X in "`find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d`"
do
    if [[ "$X" == *"git"* ]]; then
        echo "NO MATCH: $X"
        continue;
    fi
    echo "$X"
done
```

This works pretty well, except it includes the .git folder which should be excluded. For some reason, it doesn't work.

Output

```
NO MATCH: ./.git/hooks    // This is ignored like I want
./.git/info               // This isn't ignored but it should be
./.git/logs
./.git/objects
./.git/refs
./COMP 151 - Programming II/Lab 10 Resources
./COMP 151 - Programming II/Lab 11 Resources
```

I doubt it's needed, but here's the [repo](https://github.com/ShepherdJerred/harding-computer-science) on GitHub.

Comment: It does not answer your question but did you consider using the `-path` option of `find` to filter out `.git/*`? Try to add `! -path ./.git/\*` to your find command, maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your double quotes around the `find` command transform its output into one single string (with new lines in it). You are looping over one single `X` value that matches `*"git"*`. So, you print `NO MATCH:` followed by the full string (with its new lines). Proof: add `echo foobar` at the beginning of your loop and see that it gets printed only once.

You could try:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d ! -path ./.git/\*
```

which should do what you want (without the `NO MATCH` outputs).

Comment: That works. I didn't realize the quotes around the find command caused it to output one string, but it makes sense now.